# PostgreSQL memory spike upgrade from 8.2 to 9.1

Tags: postgresql, performance, memory, upgrade

We recently upgraded a few of our development computers from PostgreSQL 8.2 to 9.1, with plans on eventually upgrading our production servers.  Everything seems well with the restore of the databases, and the local websites on the dev computers. What isn't working are some reporting ETL queries.

A particular query runs in under 30 seconds on 8.2.  The core query (we've broken it out) is simply a SELECT statement with 15 joins.  For some reason, when this query is run on 9.1, PostgreSQL spikes in memory usage, acquiring all the memory available on the machine, which is 2.8 GB on my machine. Consequently, the query does not finish in any reasonable amount of time (up to 17 mins compared to 30 secs, haven't let it run forever because I need to be able to use my computer).

What we have done so far:

1. Replicated config settings for 8.2 to 9.1
2. Ran EXPLAIN on the query on both 8.2 and 9.1: should run faster on
   9.1 
   [Explain 8.2 on explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/s/3XE) (Raw data: [explain_8.2.dat](http://blainejester.com/explain_8.2.dat))
   [Explain 9.1 on explain.depesz.com](http://explain.depesz.com/s/KYA) (Raw data: [explain_9.1.dat](http://blainejester.com/explain_9.1.dat))
3. Broken the query down by removing joins. When below any 10 joins,
   the query will complete
4. Examined the joining tables for irregularities
5. Tested the query on different machines running 9.1
6. Reviewed Postgres config documentation and changelog
7. Ran VACUUM and ANALYZE on the db
8. Rebooted the machine
9. Updated kernel SHMMAX when postgres wouldn't start after reboot
10. Ran the query on CentOS box and it exhibited the same behavior
11. Ran the query on 8.4 Successfully

In my opinion, it seems fairly abnormal for PostgreSQL to use so much memory, and is alerting to the problem.  We just can't find it!

Any comments, thoughts, and ideas are appreciated!

Machine Info:

- Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit
- Intel i5-2400
- 4 GB ram
- PostgreSQL 9.1.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.5.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2, 64-bit

Comment: Could you show the `SELECT` as well?

Comment: A shot in the dark: maybe it's the hashing that uses so much memory. You can try disabling hashjoins (`set enable_hashjoin=false`) for a test and see what happens then. But this sure sounds like a problem you should report on the mailing list. I'm sure the Postgres developers would like to hear about this - as that does seem like a regression.

Comment: @dezso : Unfortunately, I cannot show the SELECT query :(

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I will try that, I remember reading something about how an outer join operates differently in a later version then 8.2 (it said something about hashing).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Changing `enable_hashjoins = off` worked, the query ran successfully. I now have a lead to research; I will post my results! Thanks!

Comment: Please do report this to the mailinglist.

Comment: What is your work_mem set to?  If it's very high that could be the cause of your problems.

Comment: @ScottMarlowe We have the `work_mem` setting set to `1MB`, the same as we had it in 8.2. Still researching the issue, but we have postponed the upgrade.

Comment: Also can you post an EXPLAIN ANALYZE so we can see what it is doing (run it, let it run to completion even if it takes a long time, and even if it is on a secondary staging server).  If that is not possible, at least run EXPLAIN and post the query plan.

Comment: the explain is above.  However there is no EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

Comment: You can also try to increase the value for `geqo_threshold` in order to avoid using the Genetic Optimizer for that number of tables: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-GEQO

Answer (score 1):

In a case like this where nothing significant has changed I think you are best off bringing this up on the PostgreSQL email lists.  Not only will you get help with your issue in terms of workarounds but if there is a planner bug somewhere the development team will be given notice so they can fix it.

This may be one of those cases where the level of help you can expect there is far better than you can expect here.